# Why is the general off-topic close reason when closed by a moderator slightly shorter than when closed by the community?

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic

I noticed a discrepancy in the general off-topic close reason (when the question is not about computer hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center). When the question is closed by five community members, the reason looks like this:

[image]

However, when a question is closed by a single moderator, the notice is a little shorter:

[image]

What explains this discrepancy? Should they be unified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

random selected to [provide a custom explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/690728/computer-freezing-randomly#comment879295_690728) instead of one of the predefined ones.

[image: Screenshot]

In that case, it's posted as a comment instead, and a generic close message is used. Note that this message is different from the close message that can be selected:

> *This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.*
>
> *This question does not appear to be about computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the help center.*

Compare the following two questions:

- [Closed only by a moderator (me) and I selected the generic 'off topic' reason](https://superuser.com/questions/691894)
- [Closed only by a moderator who selected to provide an explanatory comment](https://superuser.com/questions/694460)

Comment: The second appears to be removed for reasons for moderation. Could you update it to another one (say, to a locked one)?

Comment: @gparyani Qs that have been closed more than a few months ago use the previous close reasons from before they were redesigned in late 2013 (and are useless to this discussion), and most closed qs get auto-deleted 9 or 30 days after they're closed (a reason we don't have to delete everything manually BTW). For example, only ~20% of qs I closed in the last three months are still generally available. So it's rather common for discussions about closure that referenced qs get deleted and are only available to users with 10k+ rep. Feel free to suggest a q, I haven't found any safe from deletion.

Comment: Here's one that is locked and is closed with a custom reason. http://superuser.com/questions/694460/ffmpeg-converting-jpeg-image-sequence-to-movie-gets-error-not-enough-frames-to

Comment: @gparyani Thanks. I doubt rejected migrations live any longer though. We'll see.

Comment: Um, now the first one is deleted...Finding a new one.

Comment: Here's one: http://superuser.com/questions/632698/htaccess-to-a-folder-above-root